# Automatically select yes in "dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades"

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

How can I avoid the dialog when I run `dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`? I want to select Yes automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That’s a low-priority question, so you can skip it by specifying medium or higher:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -pmedium unattended-upgrades
```

The default answer is the current value of `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`, and if that isn’t set, “Yes”.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|unattended-upgrades/enable_auto_updates=.+|unattended-upgrades/enable_auto_updates=\"no\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor unattended-upgrades
```

Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)